# Stretching a few views in one layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to stretch ImageViews to parentlayout. I've done it with marginleft command. But it's no usefull for different screens.

I don't want to change margins with java. I wanna stretch those Imageviews for all screen. Are they any command for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.berkay.uumobil.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_home"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_marks"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/not_karti_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_calender"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/takvim_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_timetable"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dersprog_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_foodlist"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/yemek_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logout_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/menuLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[In this picture ImageViews are not stretched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZjBL.png)

[In this picture ImageViews are stretched via marginLeft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B32vi.png)

I want to see my application like second without using marginleft.

Comment: then use weight with linear layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with only the Constraint layout, you will not need the RelativeLayout.

Using the constraint chains https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain

Your layout should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout">

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/menu_marks" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_marks"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_home"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/menu_calender" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_calender"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_marks"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/menu_timetable" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_timetable"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_calender"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/menu_foodlist" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_foodlist"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_timetable"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/menu_logout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/menu_foodlist" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menu_logout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```